# Xcode Instruments CL multiple devices

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

Under OSX Lion 10.7.x i am running xcode 4.3.1
I am trying to run **multiple**  **instances** of **instruments** UI Automation in different terminal windows like:

```
 bash-3.2$instruments -w <UDID>
-t Automation.tracetemplate  /my.app  
-e UIASCRIPT /test.js 
-e UIARESULTSPATH /log
```

Problem is that if i start **terminal1** and direct after this, let **terminal2** run instrument. It stops the previous test in **terminal1**.
This used to work fine under 10.6.